# java class using with scanner to found out score total and average

Tags: java, class, java.util.scanner

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method Ave() from the type Jumsu

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method Sum() from the type Jumsu

these two error is founded ~~~

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Jumsu {
    int Kor, Eng, Math;

    public  int Sum() {
        return Kor + Eng + Math;
    }

    public  double Ave(){
        return (Kor + Eng + Math) / 3.0;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Jumsu exam = new Jumsu();
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("input num kor:"); 
        exam.Kor=scan.nextInt(); 
        System.out.println("input num eng:"); 
        exam.Eng=scan.nextInt(); 
        System.out.println("input num math:"); 
        exam.Math=scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("kor score: "+ exam.Kor + ", eng score: " + exam.Eng + ",math score: " + exam.Math + ", total: "+ Sum() +", average"+ Ave()); 
        scan.close();
        }
}
```

Comment: The error message cannot be any more clear.  Use `public static int Sum()`, etc.

Comment: First of all please make sure that you follow the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

In the print statement, while calling the `Sum()` and `Ave()` method, you need to use the class object to call it. Use `exam.Sum()` and `exam.Ave()` instead.

For any Class, you cannot call a non-static method or access the non-static variables directly. You need a Class object.

EDIT: Or you can make the `Sum()` and `Ave()` methods static. 
Use `public static int Sum()` and `public static double Ave()` when declaring the methods.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions for your little issue here. At first you could put `public double ave()` in a static context `public static double ave()` (same goes for `public double sum`) or you could use them as you have implemented them.

For now those two methods are instance methods, which means that they are property of a certain object. But so are your variables which you initialize like this: `exam.kor = sc.nextInt()`.

This line in particular states that you want to access the variable `kor` which is present int your Jumsu object and since `ave()` and `sum()` are also methods of the object you can access them by calling `exam.sum()` instead of  just `sum()`.